# Intel NUC NUC5i3RYH WOL problems

Tags: networking, suspend, intel-nuc, wakeonlan

An [Intel NUC NUC5i3RYH](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/83257/intel-nuc-kit-nuc5i3ryh.html) runs Ubuntu Server 18.04.3; it won't reliably wake-on-lan.  About every 3rd or 4th resume from sleep, Ubuntu fails to re-establish the network.

[Here are entries from journalctl showing the resume:](https://pastebin.com/DabBh2Ef)

You can see that the Ethernet adapter loses carrier on resume and then re-establishes a link at 10Mbps (it's a Gigabit NIC connected to a Gigabit switch).

Any pointers as to how to trouble-shoot this problem?  Or how to and to whom to report this bug?

Info on the Ethernet driver:

driver: e1000e
version: 3.2.6-k
firmware-version: 0.2-4

Comment: It's set to autonegotiate.  

ethtool -s $NIC autoneg off speed 1000 duplex full

...doesn't seem to "stick", in that ethtool still reports autoneg ON after that command.

The BIOS NIC setting tool only seems to support max speed of 100tx full.

After using the F9 "reset to defaults" option in the bios setting tool, the system seems better behaved.

Fingers crossed.

Comment: Apologies for the Senior Moment. Just back from break and I forgot this was an Ubuntu issue.